# Problems executing jQuery statement when changing Angular template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on a single page application that has 2 views: home, and a dashboard.

The 'home' state has a search form. When the form is submitted, the dashboard view is loaded using `$window.location.assign('/#/dashboard');`.

When the dashboard view is loaded from the search, I need to automatically set a select box value to 0. I have the code to do this, but for some reason, it is not executing when the page loads... I'm thinking this has something to do with Angular adding the new 'select' DOM element to the page when it loads.

dashboard view

```
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <!-- list all lists -->
    <select id="list-select" class="list-select" ng-model="list" ng-options="list as list.title for list in lists">
        <option value="">Select List</option>
        <!-- when the page loads from search, this will be added...
        <option value="0">search</option>
        -->
    </select>
    <!-- end list -->

    <hr class="dash">

      <!-- words in selected list -->
      <ol ng-model="list.words">
        <li ng-repeat="word in list.words" id="word-{{word.id}}">
          <p>{{ word.title }}</p>
        </li>
      </ol>
    <!-- end words -->

</div>
```

main.js

```
$("#list-select").val("0");
```

Please help!

Comment: you should consider just using the `$location` service.

Comment: I tried the $location.path service but it was not working so I just used $window.assign, is this related to the question/solution?

Comment: Interesting, I probably jumped the gun in blurting that out :]. It's probably not related to the solution, just a stylistic observation. You can disregard.

Answer (score 2):

There's a very similar question here:
[how to use ng-option to set default value of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element)

Rather than using jQuery to try to set the default value of your select list, perhaps you can stick to the angular approach:

```
<div ng-controller="yourController">
    <select ng-model="prop.value" ng-options="v for v in prop.values">
    </select>
</div>

yourApp.controller('yourController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.prop = { 
        value: 0, 
        values: []
    };

    // not the best way...
    $.getJSON('yourURL', function(data) {
        $scope.prop.values = data;
        $scope.$apply(); // you need to call this
    });

    // the better way
    $http.get('yourURL').success(function(data) {
        $scope.prop.values = data;
    }).error(function(error) {});
}]);
```

Comment: I can't use this because the list values are dynamically generated

Comment: why would that make a difference? Are you generating the values in a jquery async request? One of the major selling points of angular is that it works well when binding to dynamically generated data.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's bad practice to manipulate the DOM within your controller. Your changes won't stick whenever the model updates, and it can cause a lot of problems within your controller logic.

Instead, you'll want to manipulate the variable(s) that you're utilizing within your view. In this case, you can do something like the following within your controller after the lists array is populated:

```
$scope.lists.splice(0,0,{ value: 0, title: 'search' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was pretty much just looking for a way to set a default value for the select box.

I was able to accomplish this with [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21931119/1837874).

```
   <!-- list all lists -->
  <select ng-model="list" ng-init="list = lists[0]" ng-options="list as list.title for list in lists">
      <option value="">Select List</option>
  </select>
  <!-- end list -->
```

This sets the select box value to "0".

Thanks for all the help and tips, going to mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Just FYI, this is bad practice. If I were you, I wouldn't mark this as the correct answer unless you want to lead people astray. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546819/correct-way-to-initialise-scope-values-when-the-view-is-loaded-with-angularjs-n